# How to return column&row index of cell of certain value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
index col1 col2 col3
0      0    1    0
1      1    0    1
2      1    1    0
```

I am just stuck at a task: to find locations(indices) of all cells that equals to 1.
I was trying to use such a statement

```
column_result=[]
row_result=[]
for column in df:           
    column_result=column_result.append(df.index[df[i] != 0])
for row in df：
    row_result=row_result.append(df.index[df[i]!=0)
```

my logic is using loops to traverse the colomns and rows separately and concatenate them later
however it returns'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
would you please help me to debug and complete this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for indices for index and columns and then select them for `cols, idx` lists:

```
i, c = np.where(df.ne(0))

cols = df.columns[c].tolist()
idx = df.index[i].tolist()

print (idx)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
print (cols)
['col2', 'col1', 'col3', 'col1', 'col2']
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with filtering for final DataFrame:

```
s = df.stack()

df1 = s[s.ne(0)].rename_axis(['idx','cols']).index.to_frame(index=False)
print (df1)
   idx  cols
0    0  col2
1    1  col1
2    1  col3
3    2  col1
4    2  col2
```

Comment: the stack method is amazing! thank you